# Neo4J Cypher calculate average across multiple properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregation

In Neo4J I have the following problem:

Nodes are arranged in a tree-like or parent/child style structure. 
On the "leafs" or child nodes, every node has a set of nummerical attributes.

I need a Cypher query to calculate the average of each attribute and strore it in an attribute with the same name in the parent node.

Something like

```
MATCH (p:Parent)-[]->(c:Child) 
SET p.attrib1 = avg(c.attrib1)
SET p.attrib2 = avg(c.attrib2)
```

will do the job, BUT...

**The amount of attributes in the child-nodes should be dynamic, I do not want to change the code when a Child-node comes up with an additional attribute name. As long as the property is a decimal, the code should adapt to this.**

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do all `Child` nodes share the same set of numerical properties? And are there any `Child` properties that you do not want to average?

Comment: Some properties might not be present in every node, but there is no need to explicitly exclude any propery from averaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with help from the [APOC procedure library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures). You can *almost* do this in native Cypher, but you can't dynamically specify the name of the property to create but we can use `apoc.create.setProperty` to do this:

```
MATCH (parent:Parent)<-[]-(child:Child) 
WITH parent, child, keys(child) AS props
UNWIND props AS prop
WITH parent, prop, avg(child[prop]) AS mean
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(parent, prop, mean) YIELD node
RETURN *
```

There is a simple example in this [Neo4j Console.](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=4578r9)

Comment: Cool, I did not use APOC so far but I will give it a try later today.